# cannot query simataneousely on HIVE

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

Background information:

We have a java application which connect to HIVE using JDBC, to genarted charts .
This java application is deployed on tomcat so that users can access this application from browser . Lets says using link http://localhost/myApp

Problem Description:

When user opens the application , http://localhost/myApp , it shows charts , user can navigate to different charts etc.

but when a user B simataneuosly  opens the link, on another pc, the application does not  shows any charts to him, and after this the user who was already logged in will also stop seeing charts .

So it seems that only one user can access this application at any given moment. The momemt the second users hits the link both the user are not able to see any charts there after.

We have created this same java application which connect to MYSQL database, its works fine for any number of users, issue is only with HIVE .

---

`<!-- <context:property-placeholder location="hadoop.properties,hive.properties"/> --> <!-- This sample requires a running HiveServer2 --> <hive-client-factory id="hiveClientFactory" hive-data-source-ref="hiveDataSource" /> <beans:bean id="hiveDriver" class="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" /> <beans:bean id="hiveDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataS‌​ource"> <beans:constructor-arg name="driver" ref="hiveDriver" /> <beans:constructor-arg name="url" value="jdbc:hive2://<MYIP>:10000/advancedb" /> </beans:bean>`

Comment: Are you using Hive-Server by any chance (and not Hive-Server2)? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer

Comment: hey Dudu, Thanks for  the reply...I belive , we use HIveServer2 ...Below is the code.....

Comment: This is likely a YARN resource issue rather than Hive itself (open the ResourceManager UI)